# Get a default value for null ForeignKey in Django

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

How can I get a default value for null ForeignKey in Django. For ex:

```
class Owner(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)

class Entity(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Owner)
```

I am using DRF, so I tried this serializer:

```
class EntitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    def get_owner(self, obj):
        if obj.owner:
            return obj.owner_id
        return -1

    class Meta:
        model = Entity
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'owner')
```

This works if I change the key `owner` to `owner_id` or something else. But I cannot do it as it has dependencies elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

In Django, you can set a default value for a ForeignKey field using the default argument. You can use the `null=True` and `default` arguments in the field definition if it's possible for your case.

In your example, you can't create an Entity object without an owner so the owner of the entity will always be defined. If you can update your Entity model with the following, you will be able to provide a default when you serialize your Entity object.

```
class Entity(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Owner, null=True, default=None, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

With this change, you can remove the `get_owner` method from your serializer, and simply use owner as the field name:

```
class EntitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Owner.objects.all())

    class Meta:
       model = Entity
       fields = ('id', 'name', 'owner')
```